# Does Angular have the equivalent of JQuery find()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In angular I want to do a call similar to jQuery find() in order to make this call

```
var $vCard = $(stanza).find("vCard");
var img = $vCard.find('BINVAL').text();
var type = $vCard.find('TYPE').text();
var img_src = 'data:'+type+';base64,'+img;
```

I don't want to put in jQuery, but am having problems finding the correct location to get these details from this object (a stanza containing a VCard returned from the server).

https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Did you try to use ViewChild and ViewChildren decorators ? https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Describe your need and tell us what you have tried. There is always angular way to do stuff. You should not need to have something like `find`

Comment: Agreed, this is the correct answer for find against xml... element.querySelectorAll()

Comment: I marked this as a dupe to redirect correctly. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

Angular is built on Javascript (Typescript, but close enough), so you can always drop down to plain JavaScript. However, you may want to ask yourself if there's another way to accomplish your end goal without using `find()`. In general, Angular discourages direct DOM manipulation and instead encourages designing controllers and templates such that you can design dynamic pages without directly accessing the DOM.

For your example, you may be able to store the values of BINVAL and TYPE in the controller, thus allowing you to re-use them for your image URL. This may be a cleaner way of accomplishing what you want.

Also, *ibenjelloun* mentioned looking at the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator. If the above solution doesn't work for you, this would be a good next thing to try.